# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero (osu learning)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cant fix that error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 data_files = osulearn.dataset.all_files(OSU_FOLDER, verbose=True)
      3 if not os.path.exists('.data'):
      4     os.makedirs('.data')

File c:\Users\danil\OneDrive\Desktop\OsuLearn-master\OsuLearn-master\osulearn\dataset.py:41, in all_files(osu_path, limit, verbose)
     39 for i in range(len(replays)-1, -1, -1):
     40     if verbose:
---> 41         _print_progress_bar(replays, i, reverse=True)
     43     beatmap = _get_replay_beatmap_file(osu_path, replays[i])
     45     if beatmap is None:

File c:\Users\danil\OneDrive\Desktop\OsuLearn-master\OsuLearn-master\osulearn\_cli.py:4, in _print_progress_bar(collection, index, bar_width, buffer_width, reverse)
      1 def _print_progress_bar(collection, index, bar_width=40, buffer_width=80, reverse=False):
      2     bar_format = "\r[{done}>{todo}] {text}"
----> 4     progress = index / (len(collection) - 1)
      5     if reverse:
      6         progress = 1 - progress

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I dont know how to fix it, i tried to find in google but nothing found

Comment: You have to add part of source code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the expression

```
progress = index / (len(collection) - 1)
```

directly part this part `len(collection) - 1` in case that collection has size 1, it generates ZeroDivisionError.

You have to increate sice of collection (> one item) and all will be correct.

Comment: FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 data_files = osulearn.dataset.all_files(OSU_FOLDER, verbose=True)
      3 if not os.path.exists('.data'):
      4     os.makedirs('.data')